# Is there a way to carry out the eigenstates and eigenvalues of annihilation operator using only its matrix form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Knowing the matrix elements of annihilation operator, can I solve the eigenvalue problem without using operator method?
I got stuck when I try to compute its eigenvalue, because the eigenvalues of a upper triangular matrix should be the values on its diagonal, but they are all zero indeed, which is absurd.

Comment: I guess the tricky part relies on the fact that the matrix is infinite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to sum up ACuriousMind's answer.

Consider the following commutation relation $$[a,a^{\dagger}]\equiv aa^{\dagger}-a^{\dagger}a=1.$$

Suppose it has a finite dimensional representation, say $N$-dimensional, then it follows that $$\mathrm{tr}([a,a^{\dagger}])=\mathrm{tr}(aa^{\dagger})-\mathrm{tr}(a^{\dagger}a)=0=\mathrm{tr}(1)=N,$$

which is absurd unless $N=0$. The problem is that one implicitly assumes that $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$, which is true only in finite dimensional linear algebra.

In fact, it is known that $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ have infinite dimensional representations:
$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0  & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}, \quad a^{\dagger}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0  & \sqrt{3} & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: [Nitpick] Actually, $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(BA)$ [holds under relatively weak assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Properties) even in the infinite-dimensional case - but only if the trace exists (=the operator inside is "trace-class"). The correct resolution to the apparent contradiction $\mathrm{tr}(1) = 0$ is that $\mathrm{tr}(1)$ never exists on an infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Operators on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are **not** matrices, no matter how often physicsts may try to pretend they are. The term "matrix elements" is a (by now well-entrenched) misnomer - even though knowing all the matrix elements in one basis tells you everything you need to know about the operator, that doesn't mean treating it like a matrix will be fruitful.

In particular, results from finite-dimensional linear algebra like "The eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix are the diagonal entries" do not apply.

The coherent states $\lvert \alpha\rangle$ that are eigenstates of the annihilation operator are infinite series in the Fock basis $\lvert n\rangle$ of eigenstates of the number operator:
$$ \lvert \alpha\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-\lvert\alpha\rvert^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n}}\lvert n\rangle$$

You should not expect to be able to meaningfully say anything about such states by treating the annihilation operator as a "matrix" on the Fock basis - "matrix" is an inherently finite-dimensional concept, and so you don't "see" the infinite series of coherent states when you try to look at the annihilation operator as a matrix.

Comment: To expand on some of the points in this post, the OP would do well to consult the mathematically inclined Wilansky, Albert. "What infinite matrices can do." Mathematics Magazine 58.5 (1985): 281-283 or the more historical Bernkopf, Michael. "A history of infinite matrices." Archive for history of exact sciences 4.4 (1968): 308-358.